# Validating ZIP files on client side

Tags: javascript, zip

Is there a simple, reliable way for clientside validation of zip file content ? I know that this can be achieved with `zip.js` and `JSZip`. But I do not want to create or extract files for upload. Also I want to avoid overhead in js libraries when not absolutely needed.

I only want to open and validate zip content on file type, file size and if possible also to test if images are images or fakes. Somehow the way I can evaluate zip files on serverside with php.

Hints for pure JS solutions are welcome

Comment: If you want to check for ZIP from the client side, and want a better check than the file-ext,  you could examine the file's first few bytes (magic numbers), for ZIP I think it's  `50 4b 03 04`.  This won't protect against invalid ZIP's thought, but would prevent the casual renaming of a file to ZIP, eg. renaming a JPG to a ZIP could be detected.  Saying all this, looking at zip.js it's API allows you to open without saving.

Comment: Well, ZIP files are generally accepted when they are not fakes of course. But I think when I evaluate a zip file on its contents i will anyway see if it is a fake or not. Important is to evaluate its content before upload.